# Changing an attribute by providing a second one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var cnt = '
 <img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" />
 <div>
  <p>
    <img alt="pic2" id="zwei" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" />
   </p>
   <img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" />
  </div>';
```

I want to get/set the alt attribute of an img tag by giving the src attribute, no matter how deep the img is.

I tried:

```
$(cnt).find("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt'); //can only get the object
$(cnt).filter("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt') //can only get the alt on the root of thre DOM.
```

Also tried some combinations and .find(function(... but I simply can´t work it out.

The special thing is, I can not work directly in the DOM. My HTML is stored in the cnt variable. So I´m calling a function like this:

```
function refreshEditorAlt(src,newalt){
    var cnt=getEditorContent();
    var newcnt = cnt.replace($("img[src$='"+src+"']", cnt).attr('alt'), newalt);
    setEditorContent(newcnt);
}
```

Comment: find any console errors?

Comment: Is it html code you're searching in, or the string you've set as cnt?

Comment: I´m searching in the string, no console errors

Comment: newcnt = cnt.replace($(cnt).filter("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt'), newalt); works only if the images are not nested in other tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, note that jQuery methods can help you much:

```
var cnt = '<img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" /><div><p><img alt="pic2" id="zwei" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" /></p><img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" /></div>';
var $cnt = $("<div>" + cnt + "</div>");
//input
var src = "/data/18139/1.jpg";
var newAlt = "Xpic";
//update new alt
$cnt.find("img[src$='" + src + "']").attr('alt', newAlt);
//output
cnt = $cnt.html();
$('#out').text(cnt);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6V7hL/152/)

Note that you should wrap the `cnt` into some element (such as a `<div></div>`) so that you can use jQuery to solve your problem.

Comment: Exactely what I need. Thank You. It was all about wrapping the content

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the value:

```
$(cnt).find("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt');
```

Try this to set the value:

```
$(cnt).find("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt', newValue);
```

Comment: That´s what I already tried. If you look at my post you will see exactely this

Comment: ok, find() works only on nested img tags, filter() only on unnested. I will make a workaround like cnt='<nest>'+cnt+'</nest>'. But it´s not really sexy

Comment: @user3628218 it's not a workaround. **it's very intelligent** to do it that way. Looks like you don't even see the difference between a beautiful solution and a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the line breaks where you've defined the variable cnt. So instead you want:

```
var cnt = '<img alt="pic1" src="/data/18139/1.jpg" /><div><p><img alt="pic2" id="zwei" src="/data/18139/2.jpg" /></p><img alt="pic3" src="/data/18139/3.jpg" /></div>';
```

And then something like this will work:

```
alert($(cnt).find("img[src$='/data/18139/2.jpg']").attr('alt'));
```

Obviously you're wanting to pass the value of src into a function or something, but hopefully this should solve your problem.

Quick demo to show it works this way http://jsfiddle.net/4z5Sh/

Comment: When you set the src in your jsfiddle to 1.jpg you won´t get any alt. I did the linebreaks only here so people can better recognize the structure. In real there are no linebreaks.

Comment: @user3628218 Sorry, didn't test it enough. Although I would recommend posting your code exactly as you have it, otherwise it becomes difficult to locate the issue.